# Как удалить записи в CSV файле по условию в столбцах?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

У меня есть CSV файл с данными (7 столбцов и 6063 строк). Названия столбцов:

```
['id', 'seller', 'buyer', 'timestamp']
```

И соответствующие данные в строках. Нужно очистить этот файл от строк, где `seller=buyer`.

```
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=';', decimal=',')
dat=pd.DataFrame(data.T)
for i in dat:
    if dat[dat.columns[i]][1]==dat[dat.columns[i]][2]:
        a=dat.columns[i]
```

Вот что-то такое у меня получается, а вот с удалением столбцов (теперь это уже столбцы) у меня проблема, так как это не столбцы, которые идут по-порядку, а перечислять название 1450 столбцов как-то не очень хочется.

Подскажите, как здесь лучше поступить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом [.query()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#the-query-method-experimental):

```
data = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=';', decimal=',',  quotechar="'").query('seller != buyer')
```

Если надо сохранить обратно в CSV:

```
data.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

PS вам не нужно транспонировать DataFrame для того, чтобы отфильтровать его

PPS если вы используете Pandas то старайтесь не использовать `for loop` - это не очень эффективно

**Вот рабочий пример** с учетом того, что в вашем CSV в качестве квотирующей кавычки используется `'`:

CSV файл - `D:\temp\buyer_seller.csv`:

```
'id';'seller';'buyer';'timestamp'
1;seller-1;buyer-1;2016-01-01
2;seller-2;buyer-2;2016-01-02
3;same-1;same-1;2016-01-11
4;same-2;same-2;2016-01-22
```

Код:

```
In [21]: pd.read_csv(r'D:\temp\buyer_seller.csv', sep=';')
Out[21]:
   'id'  'seller'  'buyer' 'timestamp'
0     1  seller-1  buyer-1  2016-01-01
1     2  seller-2  buyer-2  2016-01-02
2     3    same-1   same-1  2016-01-11
3     4    same-2   same-2  2016-01-22

In [22]: pd.read_csv(r'D:\temp\buyer_seller.csv', sep=';', quotechar="'")
Out[22]:
   id    seller    buyer   timestamp
0   1  seller-1  buyer-1  2016-01-01
1   2  seller-2  buyer-2  2016-01-02
2   3    same-1   same-1  2016-01-11
3   4    same-2   same-2  2016-01-22

In [23]: pd.read_csv(r'D:\temp\buyer_seller.csv', sep=';', quotechar="'").query('seller != buyer')
Out[23]:
   id    seller    buyer   timestamp
0   1  seller-1  buyer-1  2016-01-01
1   2  seller-2  buyer-2  2016-01-02
```

Альтернативно можно просто избавиться от кавычек в именах столбцов/колонок:

```
In [27]: df = pd.read_csv(r'D:\temp\buyer_seller.csv', sep=';')

In [28]: df.columns.tolist()
Out[28]: ["'id'", "'seller'", "'buyer'", "'timestamp'"]

In [30]: df.columns = df.columns.str.replace("'", '')

In [31]: df.columns.tolist()
Out[31]: ['id', 'seller', 'buyer', 'timestamp']
```

Comment: Все бы ничего, отличная идея, вот только названия столбцов в файле реально записаны как 'seller' и 'buyer', что в данном случае не воспринимается. Огромный перечень ошибки и в конце вот это
    UndefinedVariableError: name 'seller' is not defined

Comment: Мое решение основано на том, что колонки __реально__ называются: `buyer` и `seller`. Что выводит `print(df.columns.tolist())` после чтения CSV?

Comment: @KatiaNahornaya, я обновил пример в ответе...

Comment: Это очень круто! Спасибо!

Comment: а можно еще вопрос про колонку timestamp? в данной колонке цифры что-то вроде 1469502678. Как это можно преобразовать в реальную дату/время?

Comment: @KatiaNahornaya, это UNIX timestamp (число секунд от `1970-01-01 00:00:00`), чтобы преобразовать: `df.timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp, unit='s')` ;)